# Missing Wordpress icon on `login` page after images optimization

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

After optimizing all existing images in Wordpress using plugins, I cannot see the icon on the `login` page. I have tried 3 different plugins (names?) all with the same results.
On the `login` page, where the icon should be there's an error message: `item account not registered or doesn't have a view.php file`.

As a side-effect, I also cannot make the `navbar` sticky anymore. What could be the problem?

Comment: Mind providing some details on which WP plugins you've tried so far?

Comment: Yes of course. I used: Litespeed cache(the ones with who all this problem start), wp optimizer, shortPixel, wp rocket and W3 Total Cache.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely related to a Plugin or Theme conflict. Refer to this post for steps on how to troubleshoot Wordpress, it's the first recommendation any time anything goes wrong.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/item-account-not-registered-or-doesnt-have-a-view-php-file/

Basically:

1. attempt to disable all plugins
2. switch to the default Twenty Twenty-One theme
3. if the problem goes away, enable them one by one to identify the
   source of the problem